# ASK:: Parsing function result to textfield using AJAX in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have a dropdownlist and a textfield. 
If the value of dropdownlist is change, I want to call an action in controller and parsing the result to textfield value. 
How can I do that?

Here is my View:

```html
echo TbHtml::dropDownList('isr[setting_merit_demerit_id]', $isr['setting_merit_demerit_id'], $this->getMeritList(), 
array('class'=>'span4',  // 'onchange' => 'generateNumber();', 
        'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('getMeritDemeritStatus'), 
                // 'success' =>'js:function(result){$("#tes").val(result).change();}', <--- WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?
                'data' => array('setting_merit_demerit_id' => 'js:this.value'),
                
                )
        )
); 

echo TbHtml::textField('isr[show_in_reportcard]',$isr['show_in_reportcard'], array('class'=>'span1', 'id'=>'tes'));
```

Here is my Controller:

```html
function actionGetMeritDemeritStatus(){
        $setting_merit_demerit_id = $_POST['setting_merit_demerit_id'];
        $model= SettingMeritDemeritM::model()->findByPk($id);
        
        return $model->status;

}
```

Sorry for my bad english.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your  first problem is that you are sending an AJAX request and calling a function that just returns a model. You would have to json_encode return value and then echo it. On the receiving end you would have to, in js: success, parse result and then work with that object and assign its properties as values of text fields.
Hope it helps.